# How to fit the clickable area on a button

Tags: java, button, javafx

I need to make a GUI in javafx where the buttons shape is custom made with a stylesheet
I use -fx-shape: "SVG Path"; to make the shape of my button
And sceneBuilder to make the GUI and if you need to know i use netbeans as my ide
Now when I make the custom form i want to only be able to click on that and not around it where the button is invisible

I have tried to use padding but i dont think that is the way

So if you look at this picture which is in scenebuilder
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x93ZL.jpg
you can see the white form which is what i want to be clickable
not the whole rectangle that you can see is lighted up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is not the direct answer to your question but a workaround on your Problem.
In you case i would just take the **image** which looks like that button and add a `setOnMouseClickedEventListener` 
like this-

```
ImageView img = new ImageView("https://imgur.com/a/11dRR2G");
        img.setPickOnBounds(false); // disables click on transparent areas
        img.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            //do something 
        });
```

Comment: By just calling setPickOnbounds(false) on my button it solved the problem thanks